# mysql group by last record and find remark at last record too

Tags: php, mysql

sorry miss some column my table is and data:

### tablename = tbreport

### comcode,    user_id, comname, remark, date

0010066,    32,     Wicam,  NotInterest, 2014-02-01
0010066,    32,     Wicam,  Discusing,   2014-02-05
0010066,    32,     Wicam,  Interest,    2014-02-08 
0010066,    32,     Wicam,  Pending ,    2014-02-21 
0010596,    32,     United, Interest,    2014-02-08 
0010606,    32,   SEACAM,  NotInterest  ,2014-03-08
0040025,   16,   SkyView,  Interest ,   2014-03-17

I use query below:

$uer_id='$_GET[user_id]';
$remark='$_GET[remark]';
$query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT *FROM tbreport where user_id='$uid' ORDER by date DESC ) tbreport GROUP BY comcode");

the result show the last record :

---

### comcode,    user_id, comname, remark,       date

0010066,    32,      Wicam,  Pending ,    2014-02-21 
0010596,    32,      United, Interest,    2014-02-08
0010606,    32,      SEACAM, NotInterest    ,2014-03-08
0040025,    32,      SkyView, Interest  ,2014-03-17

what I need the result like this

### when $remark = 'Interest' should show like below

### comcode,    user_id, comname, remark,       date

0010596,    32,      United,  Interest,    2014-02-08
0040025,    32,      SkyView, Interest  ,2014-03-17

And when $remark= 'Pending' should show like below

---

### comcode,    user_id, comname, remark,       date

0010066,    32,      Wicam,  Pending ,    2014-02-21

so how would I do more?
Thanks, if have any query 
Sary

Comment: You have specified the `user_id` column in your query, but it doesn't figure within your `tbreport` schema

Comment: Why is the other interest result missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m1.* FROM tbreport m1 LEFT JOIN tbreport m2 
ON (m1. comname = m2. comname AND m1.date < m2.date) 
WHERE m2.date IS NULL and m1.remark='$remark';
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.In this way it will help others looking for similar problem

Comment: thanks for ur comment, I think it is too slow to query from database and it miss my user_id because I have many user_id

Comment: I need when $remark = 'Pending' should show like below -------------------------------------------
comcode,    user_id, comname, remark,       date
-------------------------------------------
0010066,    32, Wicam,  Pending ,    2014-02-21                             when $remark = 'Interest' should show like below
comcode, user_id, comname, remark, date

0010596, 32, United, Interest, 2014-02-08
0040025, 32, SkyView, Interest ,2014-03-17 but  I don't want to show Wicam  when I select Remark as Interest because the last record of it is Pending not Interest     thanks